# Suggested edit actions in review queue no workie

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hitting approve or reject in the suggested edits queue occasionally brings up the same edit again and gets stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150153/hitting-approve-or-reject-in-the-suggested-edits-queue-occasionally-brings-up-th)

I'm seeing a lot of 'weird' behaviour in the suggested edits review queue this morning.

On *some* items in the queue, submitting a review (be it approve, reject, or edit) simply leads to *reloading* the same review page. No action appears to be recorded. When you encounter one of these items, you are stuck at that point in the queue. I have manually edited the post in question to unstick the post.

I thought I had found a work-around by clicking "Not Sure" then going back in the browser history to choose a different review action, but that action is then simply not recorded.

Example posts (now unstuck):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/799056
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/799242
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/799243

I tried this in both Safari 6 and Firefox 15 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 to make sure it's not a local issue.

Comment: (though I do applaud your use of "no workie" and I wish I had co-opted it for mine) ;)

Comment: Bah, humbug, I do wish the search on SE was of better quality..

Comment: Eh, no worries.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I can see the same behaviour.

Comment: Although possibly the same issue - might not be a duplicate as now it is not occasionally