# Nothing happens when I review a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hitting approve or reject in the suggested edits queue occasionally brings up the same edit again and gets stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150153/hitting-approve-or-reject-in-the-suggested-edits-queue-occasionally-brings-up-th)

When I go to the suggested edits page, and when I press "Approve" or "Reject" it doesn't actually approve or reject.

After I click approve or reject it will sometimes move on to the one I just tried to review. It basically looks like regardless of what I do, it basically treats my reviews as if I pressed "Not Sure".

Why aren't my reviews doing anything?

Comment: Because [Suggested edit actions in review queue no workie](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150181) today (it's a bug).

Comment: @MartijnPieters :) This question will be asked several times until the bug is resolved.