# Error in editing question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, 500-server-error

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12854817/1083946) title, as the title inserted by the user was meaningles.

The title I wanted to submit is this: "Sql error in INSERT statement".
The edit summary was this: "Inserted more descriptive title".

But on save, I received the error below:

[image: error_page]

What was wrong?

Comment: Something bad happened!

Comment: if you still have the page open, View source & you'll see the error message as an HTML comment

Comment: `The title I wanted to submit is this: "Sql error in INSERT statement".` That title is just as bad as the original one, just saying. See the edit from Bridge for a better title.

Comment: @Sathya. Unfortunatly I closed the page. But it is a valuable advice for the next time.

Comment: @Sulfurized Demonbobby. In this case I assume the edit would have been rejected. I don't think a bad title causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you try and submit an edit on top of a suggested edit for a post.  [It was caused by the same cache issue affecting this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150222/135201), a fix has just rolled out.